# Math slides looking like notes

Tags: presentations

I have seen some slides that look close to notes. For example,[this one](http://www.mathematics.jhu.edu/minicozzi/webshare/wwwroot/papers/icmslides6.pdf). I wonder what templates they are created? Not seem like by beamer, as there are more contents in each slide and not fancy at all.

Comment: `beamer` is the right tool.

Comment: "there are more contents in each slide and not fancy at all" compare to beamer.

Comment: This looks a use of the `slides` class

Comment: Possible with `beamer` with its `plain` frames.

Comment: @Swamm. Concur, that is what I often do if I need quick, fast slides for use in a classroom.  Used for proofs and homework solutions.

Comment: The linked document was indeed produced with the [`slides`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/slides) class, as shown by the source code: [`icmslides6.tex`](http://www.mathematics.jhu.edu/minicozzi/webshare/wwwroot/papers/icmslides6.tex)

Comment: @diabonas: Where do you find the source code?

Comment: @Tim I just changed the `.pdf` extension of the link to `.tex`, and there it was :)

Comment: @diabonas:  Smart a$$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example code using `slides`

```
\documentclass[landscape]{slides}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}
%
\begin{document}
$y'''+4y''+3y'=x^2\cos x-3x$
First, we solve for $y_c$. The auxiliary equation is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
m^3+4m^2+3m&=&m(m^2+4m+3)\\
&=&m(m+3)(m+1)\\
m&=&0, -3, -1
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $y_c=c_1+c_2e^{-3}x+c_3e^{-1}$.\par
For the left side, the annihilator will be 
$$(D^3+4D^2+3D)y$$ $$=D(D^2+4D+3)y$$
$$=D(D+3)(D+1)y$$
\end{document}
```

Note: You will often have to manually break the equations to keep them on the slide.

Comment: For some reason or the other, I don't get the landscape to work on my compilation??? Weird.