# What are some quick ways to turn an article into presentation slides?

Tags: presentations

My article is like

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\section*{...}
...

\section*{...}
...

\end{document}
```

I wonder what are some quick ways to turn it into slides?

Or is it viewable if projecting the article directly on a screen hanging from a wall in a classroom using  general equipments?

Comment: You can of course just project the article, but usually the problem is that an article has far too much text to make a good slide presentation so the slides need to be a summary of the highlights, which tends to be a human review process rather than a mechanical one.

Comment: Recompile using the class `slides` with the option `landscape`.  This will increase the font size so that it is nicely viewable with projection equipment.  However, a 1 page article will become 8-20 slides.  Even though this is a kludge, I do this in the classroom when I want to quickly show in class a proof or homework solution with having to build a `beamer` class presentation.

Comment: @R.Schumacher: Thanks! In your last sentence, do you mean without having to build a beamer class presentation?

Comment: @Tim:  Yes, without an build of a `beame`r.  Take any current `article` class document you have built and just change the class to `slides` and see the result.

Comment: @R.Schumacher: For slides, there is no section environment. What do you recommend to replace it and used as some subtitles? Or is there some common environment that can be shared between `slides`and `article`?

Comment: Please don't.  Please, please don't.  I've been to seminars where the person has done this and they aren't pretty.  David's right: the goal of slides should be to present a summary with **as little stuff** as possible, whereas an article can explain everything at great length.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Thanks! This is not used for any formal conference or seminar. It is just a makeshift when time is limited for preparation, or just don't want to spend much time.

Comment: @Tim Then I'd go for a blank sheet of acetate and an OHP!  Seriously, my comment is more directed at someone else reading this and thinking "Oh, I never thought of that.  Seems like a good idea.".  It might just be *me* in their audience.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: What is the method by "a blank sheet of acetate and an OHP"? In particular, what does OHP stands for? Sorry to make you potentially suffer.

Comment: @Tim OHP = Over Head Projector.  "Acetate" is a name (possibly only used in UK and over a certain age) for the clear plastic sheet that you write on.

Answer (score 1):

This is the duplicate answer I gave to [Math slides looking like notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74050/math-slides-looking-like-notes)

Here is example code using `slides`

```
\documentclass[landscape]{slides}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
$y'''+4y''+3y'=x^2\cos x-3x$
First, we solve for $y_c$. The auxiliary equation is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
m^3+4m^2+3m&=&m(m^2+4m+3)\\
&=&m(m+3)(m+1)\\
m&=&0, -3, -1
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $y_c=c_1+c_2e^{-3}x+c_3e^{-1}$.\par
For the left side, the annihilator will be 
$$(D^3+4D^2+3D)y$$ $$=D(D^2+4D+3)y$$
$$=D(D+3)(D+1)y$$
\end{document}
```

Note: You will often have to manually break the equations to keep them on the slide.

Comment: This is full of "no-no" things in LaTeX; `slides` is an obsolete class; `$$` should not be used in LaTeX; `eqnarray` neither.

Comment: Thanks! I realized two problems. (1) For slides, there is no section environment. What do you recommend to replace it and used as some subtitles? Or is there some common environment that can be shared between slidesand article? (2) An equation within `$$ ... $$` that is too long for a single line cannot be automatically continue at the next line but disappear at the right end, even without `landscape`. (3) With `landscape`, a long line of text cannot automatically continue at the next line.